# Slider inside Horizontal scroll view issue in IOS

Tags: uiscrollview, swift3, uislider

My layout has several`sliders` in a **`scroll view` which scrolls horizontally**. The issue is when I try to drag the slider thumb it is not moving instead the scroll view itself scrolls horizontally. How to fix this? (In Swift)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3 Solution**

I was facing a similar issue and fixed it by setting

```
scrollView.delaysContentTouches = false
```

**Explanation**

According to Apple Docs

> If the value of this property (**delaysContentTouches**) is true, the scroll view delays handling the touch-down gesture until it can determine if scrolling is the intent. If the value is false , the scroll view immediately calls touchesShouldBegin(_:with:in:)
>   . The default value is true.

As the word suggests it delays the content touch (i.e lowers the priority of subview's action) leading to irresponsive subview content updation during scrolling.

When this property is set to false it gives priority to the subview's action (by immediately calling **touchesShouldBegin(_:with:in:)**) leading to responsive subview content updation.

Comment: i have this problem.I am using horizantal scrollview in parentviewcontroller .i am disabling scrolling when i touch slider in chaildviewcontroller it is not working .Any suggestions please.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you call UISlider "Lazy var". Let's change it to "Let"